How to fix the Y2036 NTP problem in ANSI C on a 32bit embedded system without OS
As the year 2036 slowly (but inevitably) approaches, we have concerns about our SNTP time syncing algorithm, which is now really simple:
// NTP structure received in udp_data_buffer
uint32_t ntpStamp = ntohl(&((uint8_t *)udp_data_buffer)[0x28]);
time_t unixTime = ntpStamp - 2208988800U;
struct tm * buf;
buf = localtime(&unixTime);
uint16_t year = (uint16_t)(buf->tm_year + 1900);
uint8_t month = (uint8_t)(buf->tm_mon + 1);
uint8_t day = (uint8_t)buf->tm_mday;
uint8_t hour = (uint8_t)buf->tm_hour;
uint8_t min = (uint8_t)buf->tm_min;
uint8_t sec = (uint8_t)buf->tm_sec;
// now sync the RTC chip

Hardware platform is Cortex M3 32bit (NXP redlib), no standard OS used.
The time_t type has following declaration in libconfig-arm.h:
typedef unsigned int time_t;     /* date/time in unix secs past 1-Jan-70 */

The question is how to make this bulletproof with regard to the Y2036 (and maybe also Y2038) problem?
From what I know from the NTP spec. it does not directly support anything usable:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5905

Eras cannot be produced by NTP    directly, nor is there need to do
so.  When necessary, they can be    derived from external means, such
as the filesystem or dedicated    hardware.

Well, this is a statement I'm not comfortable with. How is there no need to do so? Why the era is not transmitted as well? If it was, no "hacks" like the following would be necessary:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2030

As the NTP timestamp format has been in use for the last 17 years,
it remains a possibility that it will be in use 40 years from now
when the seconds field overflows. As it is probably inappropriate
to archive NTP timestamps before bit 0 was set in 1968, a
convenient way to extend the useful life of NTP timestamps is the
following convention: If bit 0 is set, the UTC time is in the
range 1968-2036 and UTC time is reckoned from 0h 0m 0s UTC on 1
January 1900. If bit 0 is not set, the time is in the range 2036-
2104 and UTC time is reckoned from 6h 28m 16s UTC on 7 February
2036. Note that when calculating the correspondence, 2000 is not a
leap year. Note also that leap seconds are not counted in the
reckoning.

This means NTP ends 2104 even with this "hack". Not that I personally care about 2104, but it's not a generally applicable solution.
This is used for example here:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-1.4.1/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/ntp/TimeStamp.html
(Note for nits: The assignment uint16_t year = (uint16_t)(buf->tm_year + 1900); is also buggy in terms of the very distant Y65536 problem but this is a limitation of the used RTC chip which I cannot change.)

"How to fix" is a vague big question. Maybe start by using NTPv4? And use a different implementation of localtime and time_t which represent seconds with 64 bits.

Yeap. NTPv4 is your friend.

What's your flash data retention situation? How many years will the flash live? I take it you've already solved that much more severe problem before even considering spending time on this one?

@KamilCuk How with NTPv4? Does not differ from NTPv3, the era number is still not transmitted...

@Lundin Flash is not a problem, we have devices 14+ yrs in operation.

That's not what I asked, what does the spec say? Do you use ECC or CRC?

@Lundin 10yrs when powered on (device designed to be always powered on). We use CRC. How is this related to the Y2036 ntp problem? We plan to sell these devices even after 2026, i.e. within the official shelf life of the flash. Existing devices can be updated.

My point was that if the flash is toast after 10 years anyway, you don't need to worry about year 2036. But well, the number in the datasheet is usually an extreme value at the upper end of the temperature span.

The time from NTP has to be greater than the compilation time, as your software will run after it is compiled. Pick the current epoch, check if the time is greater than it. If it is not, means it rolled over.
uint64_t unixTime = ntpStamp - 2208988800U;
const uint64_t NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_NOW = 1715711202;
if (unitTime < NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_NOW) {
   unixTime += UINT32_MAX;
}

Roll your own implementation of localtime or use an alternative implementation of localtime that properly handles 64-bit time. One popular implementation of C standard library for embedded is Newlib https://github.com/reswitched/newlib/blob/76f6d4e21ed5b621adb75fe99a69704dca831177/newlib/libc/include/sys/_types.h#L192 . Note that localtime will be wrong anyway, as you are not able to know UTC leap seconds in advance anyway.
struct tm * buf;
buf = fixed_implementation_of_localtime(&unixTime);

The let's say "reference" implementation of localtime is in TZ  library https://github.com/eggert/tz , and it is also written in C (and still updated!) that you could also use.

Any solution for future leap seconds? Only firmware updates? Ideal would be when ntp just sent full UTC time and not timestamps which are so hard to convert to UTC.

Typically on Unix, leap seconds are stored in a file https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/timezone/leapseconds , upsteam list https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/leap-seconds.list .. It is not possible to know in advance, as it is not precisely possible to know how much earth rotation will deviate in the future from 24 hours.

Actually NTP timestamps skip leap seconds (https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/leap.html). So a simple implementation of the ntp timestamp decoding should be sufficient. Just take the ntp timestamp, divide it by 86400, and decode date and time then. I've already made some tests and it perfectly matches the online UTC time. I'll post this as a solution for further discussion.

Here is a simple code that solves the above problems.
It uses the principle of KamilCuk's answer - thanks a lot for this idea.
So this code it's not generally usable, but it will last for at least the entire NTP era (136 years). This is IMO more than sufficient for any commercial  product using NTP synchronization (I wouldn't recommend using it in the Voyager 1 firmware if it was synchronizing its time with NTP:)).
This example uses coding standards of our company.
#define dONE_MIN_SEC 60
#define dONE_HOUR_MIN 60
#define dONE_HOUR_SEC (dONE_HOUR_MIN * dONE_MIN_SEC)
#define dONE_DAY_DAY 1
#define dONE_DAY_HOUR 24
#define dONE_DAY_MIN (dONE_DAY_HOUR * dONE_HOUR_MIN)
#define dONE_DAY_SEC (dONE_DAY_HOUR * dONE_HOUR_SEC)
#define dONE_YEAR_DAY 365
#define dTWO_YEARS_DAY (dONE_YEAR_DAY * 2)

#define dCOMPILE_TIME 3924863727 //16.05.2024 16:55:27

static void vDivMod(int64_t llDividend, int64_t llDivisor, int64_t * llResult, int64_t * llRemainder)
{
  *llResult = llDividend / llDivisor;
  *llRemainder = llDividend % llDivisor;
}

static uint8_t bMaxDayInMonth(uint8_t bMonth, uint16_t wYear)
{
  switch (bMonth)
  {
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
      return 30;
    case 2:
      if ((((wYear % 4) == 0) && ((wYear % 100) != 0)) || ((wYear % 400) == 0))
        return 29;
      else
        return 28;
    default:
      return 31;
  }
}

static void vNTP_ToDateTime(int64_t llNtpTime, uint16_t * pwYear, uint8_t * pbMonth, uint8_t * pbDay, uint8_t * pbHour, uint8_t * pbMinute, uint8_t * pbSec)
{
  #define dD1 365
  #define dD4 (dD1 * 4 + 1)
  #define dD100 (dD4 * 25 - 1)
  #define dD400 (dD100 * 4 + 1)
  #define dDATE_DELTA 693594 // Days between 1/1/0001 and 12/31/1899
  int64_t llI, llDatePart, llTimePart, llY, llM, llD, llH, llS;
  if (llNtpTime <= 0)
  {
    *pwYear = 0;
    *pbMonth = 0;
    *pbDay = 0;
    *pbHour = 0;
    *pbMinute = 0;
    *pbSec = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    vDivMod(llNtpTime, dONE_DAY_SEC, &llDatePart, &llTimePart);
    // time part
    vDivMod(llTimePart, dONE_MIN_SEC, &llI, &llS);
    vDivMod(llI, dONE_HOUR_MIN, &llH, &llM);
    *pbHour = (uint8_t)llH;
    *pbMinute = (uint8_t)llM;
    *pbSec = (uint8_t)llS;
    // date part
    // calc. year
    llDatePart += dDATE_DELTA + 1;
    llY = 1;
    while (llDatePart >= dD400)
    {
      llDatePart -= dD400;
      llY += 400;
    };
    vDivMod(llDatePart, dD100, &llI, &llD);
    if (llI == 4)
    {
      llI--;
      llD += dD100;
    };
    llY += llI * 100;
    vDivMod(llD, dD4, &llI, &llD);
    llY += llI * 4;
    vDivMod(llD, dD1, &llI, &llD);
    if (llI == 4)
    {
      llI--;
      llD += dD1;
    };
    llY += llI;
    // calc. month and day
    llM = 1;
    while (TRUE)
    {
      llI = bMaxDayInMonth((uint8_t)llM, (uint16_t)llY);
      if (llD < llI)
        break;
      llD -= llI;
      llM++;
    };
    *pwYear = (uint16_t)llY;
    *pbMonth = (uint8_t)llM;
    *pbDay = (uint8_t)(llD + 1);
  };
};


int main(void) {

  uint16_t wSetYear;
  uint8_t bSetDay;
  uint8_t bSetMonth;
  uint8_t bSetHour;
  uint8_t bSetMinute;
  uint8_t bSetSecond;
  int64_t llNtpStamp;
  //... get data from NTP server - not included here (ntohl returns 32bit unsigned value - ie. the whole seconds part of the NTP timestamp)
  llNtpStamp = (int64_t)ntohl(&((uint8_t *)udp_data_buffer)[0x28]);
  if (llNtpStamp < dCOMPILE_TIME)
    llNtpStamp += 0x100000000; // time shifted to next era
  //... convert to UTC
  vNTP_ToDateTime(llNtpStamp, &wSetYear, &bSetMonth, &bSetDay, &bSetHour, &bSetMinute, &bSetSecond);
  //... write UTC to RTC chip - not included here
  vRTC_Write(wSetYear, bSetMonth, bSetDay, bSetHour, bSetMinute, bSetSecond);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

There are still some questions, eg. how to update the dCOMPILE_TIME constant in the code. I think this can be done manually each 10 years.
Any discussions to this sample code are welcome.
